# Regex for decimal number with only single dot use replace() method

Tags: javascript, regex, decimal, regex-group

I just want if someone type 10.01.1 then it will be 10.011 & if someone type something like 10.00............1 it will become 10.001

I have tried this `.replace(/(\d*)(\.){1,1}(\d*)(?=(\.)+)/g,'$1')`. But it's not working for me

Comment: Replace all dots starting from the index of the first dot until the end of the string.

Comment: @thanks shilly but what I want is to handle all the dots problem as like of 2 mentioned in the problem with the single regex. I have tried this .replace(/(\d*)(\.){1,1}(\d*)(?=(\.)+)/g,'$1') which is not working

Answer (score 3):

You could count the dots and replace onlc the firts with a dot, the rest remoce the dot.

```js
function singleDot(s) {
    return s.replace(/\./g, (c => _ => c++ ? '' : '.')(0));
}

console.log(['0.0', '0....0', '0.0...1'].map(singleDot));
```

Comment: @thanks Nina but can you please explain me the use of (0) at the end of replace function

Comment: it is the start value of `c` in a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Try `/[^\d.\s]|(?<=\.\d*)\./g;`. In short, replace every character except digits 0-9, ".", and white-spaces OR any "." that is preceded by a "." and zero or more digits 0-9. The positive look-behind `(?<=)` ensures that any "." that has a "." before it will be replaced which means that the first "." of every group will **not** be replaced. Note, that every group separated by a space or new line is considered a separate number due to **not** replacing any `\s`.

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ``` [^\d.\s] ``` | Replace any character ***BUT NOT*** digits 0-9, ".", and white-space |
| ``` | ``` | ***OR*** |
| ``` (?<=\.\d*)\. ``` | replace any "." that's preceded by a "." and zero or more digits 0-9 |

[**RegEx101**](https://regex101.com/r/RkJdv6/2)

```js
const rgx = /[^\d.\s]|(?<=\.\d*)\./g;
const str = `.08.2  5.880..
0.00..5.3
223...9.`;
const res = str.replace(rgx, "");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and the dot as a separator:

```js
const strings = [
  "10.01.1",
  "10.00............1",
  "100",
  ""
];
strings.forEach((s) => {
  const [head, ...rest] = s.split('.');
  console.log(rest.length ? head + '.' + rest.join('') : head);
});
```

Comment: I need to do by using regex only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it via regex only, you can search for an alternation that captures your first period but simply matches all others and then replace all matches with the captured group. Since the captured string will be empty for the matches that aren't captured, only the first period group is replaced by itself while the other periods are deleted. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KbDqLa/1).

Search for `(^\d*\.)|\.` and replace with `$1`.